# Jquery selector syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've come across this syntax in some code, it's breaking in IE8 but works in others, any clue what it's doing.

```
$(this.handle()).find("[id]:visible:enabled");
```

I thought it might be looking searching all elements in the current page for ids and then searching the resultant elements for attributes "visible" and "enabled" but I don't think so now. 
The developer tool in IE8 does not show any results when I search for "visible" or "enabled"!

returns Failed in IE8.

Comment: What is `this.handle()`?

Comment: *I thought it might be looking searching all elements in the current page* - nope, that would be `$("[id]:visible:enabled")`. Calling `find` will only search beneath whatever you called `find` on, not the whole page.

Comment: @Daniel - actually, if `this.handle()` returns `"*"` or `document` or `document.body` or `"body"`, then it would be exactly the same. Impossible to guess given the code provided by the author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.handle() does return something valid and $(this.handle()) is a jquery object. Find is available. The query works correctly on Chrome but not on IE8. I see the docs on these selectors now [api.jquery.com/enabled-selector](http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector) and [api.jquery.com/visible-selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector), this answers my question really . It looks like the JQuery find method is working differently on the browsers. this issue should probably be referred to jquery itself.

Answer (score 2):

This selector should find all child elements with an `id` attribute that are `visible` and `enabled`. [From this test](http://jsfiddle.net/K32Ym/2/) it appears to be working. Tested in IE8 and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context in which it is run. what is "this" and does it have a function called "handle" ? if not, then thats a reason for it to fail.

For this to work this.handle() would have to return something for jQuery to traverse, in which case it return all the elements Josiah Rudell already pointed out

Comment: this.handle() does return something valid and $(this.handle()) is a jquery object. Find is available. The query works correctly on Chrome but not on IE8. I see the docs on these selectors now http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/ and http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/, this answers my question really . It looks like the JQuery find method is working differently on the browsers. this issue should probably be referred to jquery itself.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/